# Pandas expand number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

My current dataframe is as such:

```
Index     M0      M2      M3
    0    121    2520      -3
    4    121    2521      -3
    5    161    2321      -2
...
```

Currently, I have no index 1, 2, and so on. I would like to make this available by creating empty records. The end result is like this:

```
Index     M0      M2      M3
    0    121    2520      -3
    1      0       0       0
    2      0       0       0
    3      0       0       0
    4    121    2521      -3
    5    161    2321      -2
...
```

I believe this is achievable by usual programming, but I would like to know if I can perform such operation using `pandas` library.

Comment: In addition, what I would do in usual programming is that I will convert the existing dataframe into list, and then iterate through the list to create empty rows.

Comment: Do you need to keep the old indices? A simple method would be to simply reindex the data frame.

Comment: Yes, the indices are important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `reindex` and fill the new `nan` rows with `0`:

```
df.reindex(range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()+1)).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
       M0       M2      M3
Index           
0      121.0    2520.0  -3.0
1      0.0      0.0      0.0
2      0.0      0.0      0.0
3      0.0      0.0      0.0
4      121.0    2521.0  -3.0
5      161.0    2321.0  -2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement of [the previous method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56452656/10157759) is to use the fill_value argument of `reindex`.

```
df.reindex(range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()+1), fill_value=0)
```